# How do display a progress bar for each thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tqdm

I have a class that, calls a method from other and execute it in parallel, the function that is executed has a for loop that iterates over a dataframe. How can I display a progress bar for each thread?

```
class App:
    otherClass = OtherClass()
    
    n_cpus = os.cpu_count()
    def call_multiprocessing(self):        
        with mp.Pool(processes=self.n_cpus) as executor:
            for result in executor.map(otherClass.some_method, self.dataframes):
                pass


class OtherClass()
    def some_method(self, df):
        for index, row in tqdm(dataframe.iterrows(), desc="Progress: ", total= len(df)):
            #For each thread that this function is executing 
            #I want to display a progress bar and keep her in the screen
```

The way that I'm doing each time a progress bar from a thread is updated it replaces the one that is in console. I want to show then simultaneously, is it possible? Example: If the PC has 4 CPUs, 4 progress bars.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Progress bars should only run in the main thread. Use a queue or similar to pass the status to the main thread and display from there.

[Here](https://github.com/Rockhopper-Technologies/enlighten/blob/main/examples/multiprocessing_queues.py) is an example using [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) and [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), but you should be able to achieve something similar using the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) modules.